# Angular return html element

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, angularjs

**Hi there,**

So I'm experimenting with AngularJS as a frontend framework and Wordpress as backend. I used a JSON wordpress plugin and load the content via $http request in Angular.

The content is a string and I want to extract some images from it. I tried to do it like this:

```
BlogPost.prototype.images = function()
{
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = this._data;

    var imgs = element.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var array = [].slice.call(imgs);

    return array;
}
```

And my html:

```
<div class="media">
    <p class="img" ng-repeat="imgs in post.images()" ng-bind-html="imgs">
</div>
```

It doesn't work the output on my the output on my html page is: *[object HTMLImageElement]* and in the console I get the following error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig (*Error: error:infdig Infinite $digestLoop*) Is there another way to get some html elements out of the string and return them back to my angular template?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing an Angularjs wordpress front-end project here the github code:
https://github.com/altrovideo/wordpress-angularjs

I've solved your issue using https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ 
and this code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="post in filteredArticoli">
      <td ng-bind-html="post.title"></td>
      <td><a ng-href="{{post.featured_image.source}}"><img ng-src="{{post.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.thumbnail.url}}"></a></td>
      <td ng-bind-html="post.excerpt"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```